# RAILO with sftp

Tags: coldfusion, sftp, railo

RAILO support sftp mapping which we can use with cffile tag for various operation, more information at 
https://github.com/getrailo/railo/wiki/Railo-Resources#mappings

I can create mapping like

```
this.mappings["/ftpdir"] = "ftp://username:password@server.com/dir";
```

and work perfectly fine for me for copy/moving etc.
Only issue is that in case I want to use SFTP instead of FTP what should be change in mapping.

**Update**
I have notice in SFTP was using port 22 so same I have tried to supplied in ftp path as below

```
this.mappings["/ftpdir"] = "ftp://username:password@server.com:22/dir";
```

but doesn't work. RAILO tried to search directory in my local computer instead of FTP server.

Thanks,
Pritesh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sftp instead of ftp, change the protocol in URL to sftp://.

I do not think you need to specify port 22 explicitly. It's defuault for SSH/SFTP.

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried that as well but in that case it also showing me local path as result. 
I tried with cfsftp (http://web.archive.org/web/20070116064222/http://www.socialpoints.com/blog/client/includes/cfsftp1_3_2.zip) and able to work perfectly fine. As initially it was showing me unknown host error but there is way to add host file which automatically downloaded by cfstp.
Is there anyway to know error occured in RAILO mapping.